# Matching filter expression text

Tags: .net, regex

I have to build a filter expression dynamically. That's why I would like to match and replace filter. For example I have the following string:

```
string input = " (Country = \"Brazil\" OR Country = \"Canada\") AND CompanyName.Contains(\"Contoso\") ";
```

I want to replace, CompanyName.Contains(\"Contoso\") where Company Name may have different name.

Here is my code:

```
string input = " (Country = \"Brazil\" OR Country = \"Canada\") AND CompanyName.Contains(\"Contoso\") ";
string replacement = "123456";
string pattern = @"(CompanyName.Contains\()";

// \"[^\"]*\"

Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

It seems that my filter expression is wrong. What it should be?

Comment: I think you need a [`\bCompanyName\.Contains\([^()]*\)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbCompanyName%5c.Contains%5c(%5b%5e()%5d*%5c)&i=+(Country+%3d+%22Brazil%22+OR+Country+%3d+%22Canada%22)+AND+CompanyName.Contains(%22Contoso%22)+&r=123456)

Comment: Great, I posted an answer, please see below. If you have more concerns about this please feel free to drop a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your expression, the dot is not escaped and it only matches part of the required `CompanyName.Contains("Contoso")` stopping right after the opening `(`.

You can use

```
var pattern = @"\bCompanyName\.Contains\([^()]*\)";
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CbCompanyName%5C.Contains%5C(%5B%5E()%5D%2A%5C)&i=%20(Country%20%3D%20%22Brazil%22%20OR%20Country%20%3D%20%22Canada%22)%20AND%20CompanyName.Contains(%22Contoso%22)%20&r=123456)

The `\b` matches a word boundary, an escaped dot matches a literal dot and `\([^()]*\)` matches  a `(` followed with 0+ characters other than `(` and `)` (due to the negated character class `[^()]`).